# SQL: 'union all' for all tables that start with a given pattern

Tags: loops, union, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014

I am currently using this Query to create a View:

```
select *
from ((SELECT 'category1'   as item, * FROM itemList_category1) union all
      (SELECT 'category2'   as item, * FROM itemList_category2) union all
      (SELECT 'category3'   as item, * FROM itemList_category3)
     ) t
```

Which works well to combines all categories into a long list. However as my list of categories grows, I need to manually alter this View.

Is there a way to perform same, but by looping automatically over all tables that start with "itemList_" ?

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL for this, whose syntax is very vendor specific.  That being said, which database are you using?

Comment: What is your database? You can develop a procedure to read the table names from the database SCHEMA (Information schema) and update your view automatically.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen same ideia almost at same time! Cheers!

Comment: sorry this was missing indeed. I am using SQL Server 2014, and I have edited my question.

Comment: Try This : SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'itemList_%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple and doesn't require cursors, which are inefficient

```
--important to use correct database!
use MY_DATABASE
go
declare @query nvarchar(max) = N''
select @query += 'select ''' + name + ''' [item], * from MY_DATABASE.dbo.' + name + ' union all ' from sys.tables
where name like 'itemList%'
--remove last UNION ALL
set @query = LEFT(@query, len(@query) - 9)
EXEC @query
```

Comment: Thank you! this looks much simpler indeed. I have tried to create a View with that but it tells me "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'use'". I understand this might be because it is not a query itself, but a script that creates a query?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dynamic SQL within cursor.

Try this :

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @TableName nvarchar(50)

set @sql = 
'
select *
from (
'

DECLARE cursor_tables CURSOR FOR
SELECT top 3 name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE 'itemList_%'

OPEN cursor_tables   
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN  

set @sql = @sql + '(select ' + replace(@TableName,'itemList_','') + ' as item,  * FROM ' + @TableName +  ') union all'   + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @TableName

END

CLOSE cursor_tables   
DEALLOCATE cursor_tables

set @sql = substring(@sql, 0, len(@sql)-11)

set @sql =  @sql + ')t'


print @sql
```